# If $U_1,U_2\subseteq U, U$ linear independent set then $(<U_1> \cap <U_2>)= <(U_1\cap U_2)>$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I take an element $v$ in $(<U_1> \cap <U_2>)$ why this element can be described as :

$v=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_iz_i+\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+n}\lambda_{i}x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mu_iz_i+\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m}\mu_i y_i$

?

where $z_1,..,z_n\in U_1\cap U_2,x_{k+1},...,x_{k+n}\in U_1\backslash U_2$ and $y_{k+1},...,y_{k+m}\in U_2\backslash U_1$

I thought every element of  $(<U_1> \cap <U_2>)$  must be a linear combination of vectors that are bothin $U_1$ and $U_2$

My tought process so far:

Let $x\in U_1\cap U_2\Rightarrow x\in U_1$ and $x\in U_2$

We have
$$<U_1>\cap <U_2>:= \{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_iu_i,u_i\in U_1,n\in\mathbb{N},\lambda_i\in\mathbb{F}\}\cap\{\sum_{j=1}^{k}\mu_ju_j,u_j\in U_2,k\in\mathbb{N},\mu_j\in\mathbb{F}\}$$

I choose $m=1,n=1,\mu=\lambda=1,u_i,u_j=x $ and then I have proved

$x\in <U_1>\cap <U_2>\Longrightarrow U_1\cap U_2\subseteq <U_1>\cap <U_2>\Longrightarrow <U_1\cap U_2>\subseteq <U_1>\cap <U_2>$

Because Intersections of subspaces are again subspaces. And $<A>$ is the smalleset subspace that contains $A$.

To prove the next part the original proof proceeds with the Claim in the head of the Body of the Question.

Comment: "I choose $m=1,n=1,\mu=\lambda=1,u_i,u_j=x $" But you can not "choose" these, the definition provides you with some, which may be different.

Answer (score 0):

I take a $x\in <U_1>\cap<U_2>:=W$

If I take a random linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu_ia_i$ with Elements of $U_1$ (resp $U_2$). Then some of the vectors might be in the intersection, i.e $a_i\in U_1\cap U_2$ while others might be not, i.e $a_i\in U_1\backslash U_2$ (resp $U_2\backslash U_1$). To be a Vector of the set $W$m $x$ must be written in the form

$$x=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_iz_i+\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+n}\lambda_{i}x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mu_iz_i+\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m}\mu_i y_i$$

I.e it must be a linear combination of $<U_1>$ as well as $<U_2>$.

The reason why one distinguishes between $a_i\in U_1\cap U_2$ and $a_i\in U_1\backslash U_2$ (resp $U_2\backslash U_1)$ is because i the next step one can rewrite the equation above to:

$$0=\sum_{i=1}^{k}(\lambda_i-\mu_i)z_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^{k+n}\lambda_ix_i-\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+m}\mu_iy_i $$

The linear independens then yields $\lambda_1=\mu_1,....,\lambda_k=\mu_k$ and $\lambda_{k+1}=…\lambda_{k+n}=\mu_{k+1}=…=\mu_{k+m}=0$. Therefor x is a linear combination of vectors which are both in $U_1$ and $U_2$. I.e: $x\in <U_1\cap U_2>$